# a program in visual studio 2010 crushes and I dont know the reason for that

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2010, operator-overloading

I have written a program in c++, which implements some operations on matrix using class and operations.

The code is shown below:

**matrix.h**

```
#ifndef Matrix_h
#define Matrix_h
#include <iostream>

class Matrix
{
private:
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int **Mat;

public:
    Matrix ( int rows, int cols);
    Matrix (const Matrix &other);
    ~Matrix ();
    int* & operator[](const int &index) const ;
    void operator=(const Matrix &other );
    Matrix  operator -()const;
    Matrix  operator -(const Matrix &other)const;
    Matrix  operator +(const Matrix &other)const ;
    Matrix  operator *(const Matrix &other)const;
    Matrix  operator *(const int &num)const;
    int getMatrixRows(const Matrix &other){return other.rows;}
    int getMatrixCols(const Matrix &other){return other.cols;}

    friend  Matrix operator *(const int & num,const Matrix &m)
    {
     return (m*num);
    }


    friend Matrix operator +(const int &num,const Matrix &t)
    {
     return (num+t);
    }


    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Matrix &m)
    {
    for (int i=0; i < m.rows; ++i) {
        for (int j=0; j < m.cols; ++j) {
            os << m.Mat[i][j] << "  " ;
        }
        os << '\n';
    }
    return os;
}
};

#endif
```

**matrix.cpp**

```
#include "Matrix.h"
#include <iostream>

Matrix::Matrix(int n_rows, int n_cols) //constructor
{
    rows = n_rows; 
    cols = n_cols;

    Mat = new int*[rows];
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
       Mat[i] = new int[cols];
       for(int j = 0; i < cols; ++j)
           Mat[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix &other) //copy constructor
{
    rows = other.rows;
    cols = other.cols;

    Mat = new int*[rows];    
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        Mat[i] = new int[cols];
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
            Mat[i][j] = other.Mat[i][j];
    }
}

Matrix::~Matrix()  //deconstructor
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        delete Mat[i];
    delete[] Mat;
}


int* & Matrix::operator [](const int &index) const  // overloading operator []
{
  return  Mat [index];
}



void Matrix::operator=(const Matrix &other )   // overloading operator =
{
    if(Mat !=other.Mat && cols==other.cols && rows==other.rows)
     {
       for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
            Mat[i][j]=other.Mat[i][j];
     }
}


 Matrix  Matrix::operator-()const   // overloading operator -
{
    Matrix temp(rows,cols); 
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
            temp.Mat[i][j]=Mat[i][j]*-1;
   return temp;
}


 Matrix  Matrix::operator +(const Matrix &other)const  //add 2 matrix
{
    Matrix temp(rows,cols);  
    if (rows!=other.rows ||cols!=other.cols)
    {
       for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
            temp.Mat[i][j]=Mat[i][j];
       return temp;
    }
    else
     {      
         for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
             for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
                 temp.Mat[i][j]+=other.Mat[i][j]+Mat[i][j];
     }
    return temp; 
}





Matrix  Matrix::operator *(const Matrix &other)const   //multiplay matrix on the right
{
    if (cols!=other.rows)
    {
      Matrix temp(cols,rows);
      for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
            temp.Mat[i][j]=Mat[i][j];
      return temp;
    }
    else
    {
      Matrix temp(cols,other.rows);  
      for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
          for(int j=0;j<other.cols;j++)
            for(int k =0;k<cols;k++)
                temp[i][j]+=Mat[i][k]*other.Mat[i][j];
      return temp;          
    }

}




Matrix  Matrix::operator *(const int &num)const   //multiplay with number
{
    Matrix temp(rows,cols);
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
       for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
            temp.Mat[i][j]=Mat[i][j]*num;
    return temp; 
}

Matrix  Matrix::operator -(const Matrix &other)const //matrix subtraction 
{
    Matrix temp(rows,cols);  
    if (rows!=other.rows ||cols!=other.cols)
    {
       for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
            temp.Mat[i][j]=Mat[i][j];
       return temp;
    }
    else
     {

         for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
             for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
                 temp.Mat[i][j]+=Mat[i][j]-other.Mat[i][j];
     }
    return temp;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Matrix.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
  Matrix m(2, 2);
  m[0][0] = 2;  
  m[1][1] = 2; 
  cout << m << endl; 
  m = m; 
  const Matrix s = -m; 
  cout << m << endl << s << endl; 
  m = s + 2 * -m * m * 2 - s; 
  cout << m << endl << s << endl;  
  cout << s[1][1] << endl;
}
```

**The expected output is :**

```
    2 0 
    0 2  
    2 0
    0 2  
   -2 0
    0 -2  
   -16 0
    0 -16  
   -2 0
    0 -2  
   -2
```

Well, the program seems to be compiled well , since there is no warnings or errors. However, when I run this program - it crushes with none input.
The dubugger is pointing the line   `Mat[i][j] = 0;`  to be suspicious (this line is in the constructor). Hopefully someone will be able to help.

Comment: Visual studio has an integrated debugger, did you try using it?

Comment: Read the loops in your constructor very, very carefully.

Comment: "_The output from the dubugger shown:_" It wouldn't tell you what's wrong with your code. By "Did you try using it?" I meant, "Did you try stepping through your code, with it?" Which is, how you use a debugger. I fail to understand, why most people who hear about an existence of a debugger, expect it to show exactly what's wrong. When in reality - debugging is the majority of work one does, when developing.

Comment: I have just edited my post, and I am truly sorry for posting incorrectly before then.

Comment: Exercise: rename `i` to `row` and `j` to `column`, and you will see the bug from a mile away.

Comment: @NOA_ROTH Your `operator =` is weird in two ways.  1) It does not return a reference to the current object, and 2) It should not need to do tests to see if the Matrix dimensions are the same.   When a programmer wants to make two objects equal, they mean it.  You're supposed to be making one Matrix equal to the other, meaning you need to change dimensions to match what is passed in and then assign the data.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  Could you explain it more in detail ?

Comment: Use one std::vector instead of multiple new.

Comment: BTW, the `main` function returns `int`.  Always.

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ faq matrix".  It's been done already.

Comment: @NOA_ROTH -- `Matrix A(10,10);  Matrix B(20,20);  A = B;` -- As a programmer, what does that mean to you?  Doesn't it mean to make the `A` matrix logically equal to the `B` matrix in terms of size and data?   The way you wrote your `operator =`, the `A` rejects the request to make it equal to `B` -- that is not intuitive to anyone reading those 3 statements, and IMO would be considered a very bad design, if not a broken design.

Comment: why? how would you rewrite it?

Comment: @NOA_ROTH [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77b2ee1db87243c5)

Comment: PaulMcKenzie@ I am not sure I entirely understand this implementation.

Comment: How might  I  implement it without using std ?

Answer (score 0):

The line  `for(int j = 0; i < cols; ++j)`   should   be

```
 for(int j = 0; j < cols; ++j).
```

Now it works.